# listview listner and adapter to handle word suggestion

Tags: android, textview, adapter

```
public class DictionaryListActivity extends Activity {

    TextView userTextView;
    EditText searchEditText;
    Button searchButton;
    ListView dictionaryListView;

    String logTagString="DICTIONARY";
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();


    DictionaryDatabaseHelper myDictionaryDatabaseHelper;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary_list);

        Log.d("DICTIONARY", "second activity started");

        userTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.personTextView);
        userTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(FragmentA.USER_NAME_STRING2));

        searchEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
        searchButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        dictionaryListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionaryListView);

        myDictionaryDatabaseHelper=new DictionaryDatabaseHelper(this, "Dictionary", null, 1);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(FragmentA.SHARED_NAME_STRING2, MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean initialized=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("initialized", false);

        if (initialized==false) {
            //Log.d(logTagString, "initializing for the first time");
            initializeDatabase();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("initialized", true);
            editor.commit();

        }else {
            Log.d(logTagString, "db already initialized");
        }

        allWordDefinitions=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords();
        dictionaryListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
                if (view==null) {
                    view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }
                TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
                Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
                textView.setTypeface(font);
                textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).word +"\n" + allWordDefinitions.get(position).definition );

                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return allWordDefinitions.size();
            }
        });

        dictionaryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent intent =new Intent("android.intent.action.JAM");
                intent.putExtra("word", allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);
                intent.putExtra("definition", allWordDefinitions.get(position).definition);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string=searchEditText.getText().toString();
                WordDefinition wordDefinition=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getWordDefinition(string);

                if (string ==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(DictionaryListActivity.this, "No word Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (wordDefinition==null && string !=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(DictionaryListActivity.this, "Word not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                }else {
                    Intent intent =new Intent("android.intent.action.JAM");
                    intent.putExtra("word", wordDefinition.word);
                    intent.putExtra("definition", wordDefinition.definition);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void initializeDatabase() {
        InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        DictionaryLoader.loadData(bufferedReader, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper);

    }
}
```

I have provided my class file,
I want the textview to be dynamically show the result when i enter words in textbox..I mean like add an listner.I want the codes which will help it work not the syntax or something :)

Comment: Can u edit my class and do it for me

Answer (score 0):

[AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is the best suitable for this, This [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom adapter and override filter to match your requirment like below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private int rowViewResourceId;
    private List<String>  = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> backupstringList = null;

    private TextView widgetName;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int rowViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, rowViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.rowViewResourceId = rowViewResourceId;
        this.stringList = objects;
        backupstringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        backupstringList.addAll(stringList);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.stringList.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int index) {
        return this.stringList.get(index);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        //Do whatever you are doing
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                stringList = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                constraint = ((String) constraint).toLowerCase();
                stringList.clear();
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    stringList.addAll(backupstringList);
                } else {
                    for (String wp : backupstringList) {
                        stringList.add(wp);
                    }

                }
                results.count = stringList.size();
                results.values = stringList;

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

and use this filter in your activity like

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(<search text>);
```